# How to configure a concrete AutoMapper profile in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a condition to decide what type of DI to make e.g.

```cs
if (condition)
{
   services.AddScoped<Interface, Class1>
   services.AddSopped<Interface1, Class2>
}
else
{
   services.addScoped<Interface, Class2>
   services.AddSopped<Interface2, Class3>
}
```

In Class2 and Class3 I have different models in usage.
For the models that I use in Class1 I have a Profile1 and for the models that I use in Class2 I have Profile2. These profiles are in the same assembly and they have custom resolvers.

```cs
public class Profile1: Profile
{
    CreateMap<SomeInterface1, SomeClass1>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.param1,
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver1>());

public class Profile2: Profile
{
    CreateMap<SomeInterface2, SomeClass2>()
        .ForMember(
            dest => dest.param2,
            opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver2>());
```

When I`m trying to configure an AutoMapper I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Interface2' while attempting to activate 'CustomerResolver2'.

I've tried to configure AutoMapper manually, but because these Profiles are in the same assembly the AutoMapper configure 2 Profiles and then I get that error because I have not made a DI.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Just to add, it seems to be an issue with your injection and not automapper. Yet it would be helpful if u can clarify the question more by adding you constructor, automapper profile registration.

Comment: Generally there is no relation between DI and automapper. Check the constructor where your are injecting. Its seems Class3 has a dependency on Interface2, something like Class3(Interface2 _inter2)

Comment: I have updated the question, check it out.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code formatting. If you're unfamiliar with CommonMark/Markdown, this is worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core